# How to simplify this pattern matching?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Suppose I have a function like this:

```
def foo(x: Int): Int = ???

def bar(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = xs map {
  case x if (x > 0) => x
  case x if (foo(x) > 0) => foo(x) + 1
  case _ => 0 
}
```

The problem is that `foo` is called *twice*. How would you write `bar` to call `foo` only once ?

Comment: Beware guards - https://twitter.com/travisbrown/status/714125150711451648

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
case x => 
  val y = foo(x) 
  if(y > 0) y + 1 else 0
```

Or `map` twice:

```
 list
   .map {
     case x if x > 0 => x
     case x => foo(x) + 1
   }.map { 
     case x if x < 0 => 0
     case x => x
   }
```

Or wrap foo into `Option`, and filter:

```
 ... 
 case x => Option(foo(x) + 1).filterNot(_ < 0).getOrElse(0)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def foo(x: Int): Int = ???

def bar(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = xs.map {
   x =>
     lazy val food = foo(x)
     if(x > 0) x
     else if (food > 0) food + 1
     else 0
}
```